# Converting a column containing UTC values to EST values in Snowflake

Tags: timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to convert a column that contains UTC values to EST values.

| LOAD_DATE_UTC |
| --- |
| 2022-03-23 20:59:51.000 |

**Expected output:**

| LOAD_DATE_UTC | LOAD_DATE_EST |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-23 20:59:51.000 | 2022-03-23 16:59:51.000 |

Approach tried:

```
SELECT LOAD_DATE_UTC, 
CAST(LOAD_DATE_UTC AS TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9)) AS LOAD_DATE_EST
FROM TABLE_A
```

The above approach seem to be returning the same value as is.
Please advise how I can convert the column to EST values which is set as Local Time Zone at Snowflake configuration level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the idea is to convert to EST (target)-
So following approach will suit: CONVERT_TIMEZONE( <source_tz> , <target_tz> , <source_timestamp_ntz> )

```
SELECT LOAD_DATE_UTC, 
CONVERT_TIMEZONE(LOAD_DATE_UTC,'America/New_York',LOAD_DATE_UTC::timestamp_ntz)
FROM TABLE_A
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/convert_timezone.html#examples

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave ```CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/New_York',LOAD_DATE::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)```, I am getting 5 hours difference. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the difference 4 hours or 5 hours, can you please check and share output if possible?

Comment: The query that i used - ```SELECT CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/New_York',LOAD_DATE::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)
FROM TABLE_A;``` Output - |2021-12-24 07:51:24.000|2021-12-24 12:51:24.000|

Comment: Seemingly Snowflake uses only EST. It is not able to recognize EDT. EST Vs UTC - 5 hours and EDT Vs UTC - 4 hours.

Comment: Would ```LOAD_DATE - INTERVAL '4 hours'``` help?

Comment: That is like hard-coding. I wont say is the right approach, but more like a work-around.

Comment: And in case you are looking to hard-code, perhaps you can use this   select CONVERT_TIMEZONE( 'EST' ,'2021-12-24 07:51:24.000 -0100' );

OR, select CONVERT_TIMEZONE( 'EST' ,'2021-12-24 07:51:24.000 -0100' )::timestamp_ntz;

Answer (score 1):

try using convert_timezone.

```
select '2022-03-23 20:59:51.000' as EST,
convert_timezone('UTC', '2022-03-23 20:59:51.000') as utc_time_zone;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave ```CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC','America/New_York',LOAD_DATE::TIMESTAMP_NTZ)```, I am getting 5 hours difference. What am I doing wrong here?